# Best joomla moddle inegration extension

Tags: joomla, moodle

Please let me know the best extension to integrate moodle with joomla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About 9 months ago I integrated Joomla & Moodle and at that time there was only one such plugin, called Joomdle:
http://www.joomdle.com/

It's free and support is very good. I recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a full list of available Joomla-Moodle integration. The pros and cons of each solution is also described in the same page:

http://docs.moodle.org/20/en/Integrations#Joomla